# is there fillArc function available for AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

is there this kind of function available in AS3:

```
    g.fillArc(5,5,w-10,h-10,90,-360*value/limit);   // JAVA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably your solution: http://www.pixelwit.com/blog/2008/12/drawing-closed-arc-shape/

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of. You should be able to simulate its behavior by appropriate call(s) to [`Graphics.curveTo()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/display/Graphics.html#curveTo%28%29), though. It's determining the correct control points that makes it inconvenient, but its doable. [Here's a document](http://www.whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/) on how to approximate a circle with Bezier curves, this could come handy when determining the correct parameters.